# Using OAuth instead of Basic authentication?

Tags: security, oauth, basic-authentication

We have a web service, which currently uses Basic Auth over https to authenticate user requests. We also have a website which uses the service, and a native Windows client, which also uses the web service. I've read about OAuth, and it seems like it's always used for giving or getting access to external resources, i.e. delegation, but I'm trying to understand if it's a replacement for Basic Auth.

I'm not quite sure how all the parts fit together. Do you use Basic over https to the website to retrieve a secret and then have the javascript which is making requests to the REST services authenticate to the web service using OAuth instead of Basic?

It seems that at some point the user needs to enter their username and password into a form. I'm not sure what typically happens next. Is this even a use case for OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

If you have local database accounts for the users (Resource owners) then you can replace the basic authentication with the one of OAuth flow named "**Resource Owner Password Credentials**" flow.
It is very simple flow where you issue HTTP post to an end point specified in your HTTP server usually named `/token` The content-type for this HTTP Post action is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, so the post body will contain something like this `grant_type=password&username=Taiseer&password=SuperPass`

One the request is sent to the `/token` end point the server will validate the user credentials against your database store, and if all is valid it should generate a token (signed string) which contains all the claims for this resource owner (user). Then your client application should present this token in the Authorization header with each call to any protected end point using `bearer` scheme. 
This token expires after certain period and you can configure this from the AuthZ server. You can read my detailed blog post [Token Based Authentication](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) to get more details.

Comment: What you describe isnt OAuth, its a token based security method of your own. I had considered a similar scheme, but wanted to use a standard.

Comment: Additionally, your article calls for forms based auth over http, which would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Nop I disagree with you, this a single flow of OAuth flow, this is not form authentication and I've mentioned that this should be done over https in production. Seems you didn't read well. Read more about this flow: [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.3.3).

Comment: Sorry about that. I had only been reading about OAuth 1.0a, so I wasn't familiar with "Resource Owner Password Credentials". I had read a little about OAuth 2.0, but is sounded like there were some security issues. Especially since one of the main developers left the project.
Thanks for the correction, I'll re-read your article and revisit OAuth 2.0

Comment: You are welcome, never mind :) Well but all the big players (Google, Facebook, MS) are adopting it so I believe it won't die easily. Let me know if you need further help.